# Bottom padding doesn't seem to be showing when the window is too small

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm trying to make make the popup have some extra blank space around and I am using `margin: auto;` and `position:relative;` to center it because `justify-content: center;` doesn't allow scrolling to the top or bottom. I tried a lot, positioning, bottom and top values but no success. At this point, I had to come here. CSS isn't my power, what should I do?

```css
@media screen and (max-height: 812px) {
  body .read {
    padding: 12px 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  body .read div {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 812px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    min-height: min-content;
  }
  body .read div:nth-child(1) {
    margin: auto;
  }
  body .read div .containerbox {
    height: 100px;
    min-height: auto;
    max-height: 420px;
  }
  body .read div .interact {
    height: auto;
    min-height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="read">
  <div>
    <h1>Message Title</h1>
    <h2>2020/08/01</h2>
    <h2>John</h2>
    <div class="containerbox">
      <h3>Message Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="interact">
      <button><h2>Reply</h2></button>
      <button><h2>Erase</h2></button>
      <button><h2>Close</h2></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you actually want here, can only guess, that you might perhaps want to apply the padding to `body .read div`, and not `body .read`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand completely your goal. But I would use the following:

```
  body .read div:nth-child(1) {
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
```